# Tidal loan insurance

Tags: loans, scams

I received notification of approval from Lending Club.  He said it was structured as a "tidal loan" and an insurance fee would need to paid upfront to allow funding.

Does this sound legit??

Thanks

Comment: The only reference I see to "tidal loans" is a sketchy blog site that describes them as interest-only loans. I'd avoid interest-only loans AND anything that requires upfront "insurance" payment. If you don't understand the terms of the loan fully then walk away.

Comment: Did you solicit the loan or did someone from "Lending Club" reach out to you? I'm also wondering if there might be a typo/misunderstanding of tidal vs title, as in title insurance?

Comment: I think he "mistyped" also....Lending Club reached out to us

Comment: Why? Have you applied for a loan?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that they meant "title loan" and that they either have poor language skills or are unfamiliar with financial terminology. My understanding for this type of loan is that usually your car title is used as collateral (hence the name), so having insurance too seems a little odd. The terms are unusual too. Usually, if you have a loan that requires PMI, my understanding is that that would be a monthly fee built in to the payments, not as a one-time fee.

Asking for money in order to receive money is a common scam tactic most commonly associated with [advance-fee scams](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam) (aka "Nigerian scam"). Odds are, if you pay that money, there'll magically be some other problem that requires you to pay even more.

As a now-deleted answer pointed out, you should reach out to the company directly to verify the legitimacy of this before you pay anything.